# Show popup on marker click in openlayers 3

Tags: php, mysql, openlayers

Below is my code. This is working fine but I want to know how to give a popup onClick of marker? The content in the marker I want to show dynamically fetching from mysql database using php, but for now I want to know how to give different popup for each marker here?

```
<div id="mapdiv"></div>

<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script> 
<script>
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 13.0161, 22.2845 ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);
var cmark = [13.0161, 22.2845];
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));      

var zoom=8;
map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);

var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");

// Define an array. This could be done in a seperate js file.
// This tidy formatted section could even be generated by a server-side script (jsonp)
var markers = [
   [ 73.0161, 26.2845 ],
   [ -0.1244324, 51.5006728 ],
   [ -0.119623, 51.503308 ]
];

//Loop through the markers array
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

   var lon = markers[i][0];
   var lat = markers[i][1];

    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( lon, lat ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            {description: "marker number " + i} ,
            {externalGraphic: 'marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );             
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
}                        
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is not openlayers 3 . If you need, i can post a working solution for openlayers 3.

Comment: okay sure you can. But I want to show multiple markers and their respective popup which will come from my php code. Separate popup for each marker.

Comment: I can only direct you to how to accomplish it (been some time since i used openlayers2). First, you have to catch the select event of the marker ( feature ) . For this , you need to add a component to your map. After you catch the event, you should distinguish your feature types, using one of its properties. This completeley depends on your application logic.Then you can send a MarkerType key to your php page, return a partial html specific to that marker type, insert it into popup template and show the popup.Check out OpenLayers 2 examples .

Comment: Also , here's a link  that may help. http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html  Don't forget to check openlayers 2 examples. Search for keywords "select feature","popup"

Comment: If you are new to openlayers, openlayers 3 is completely different  from Openlayers 2 (rewritten) so my suggestion is not to waste time with an obsolete library unless you have to do some legacy code maintenance. If you are new to programming, then it will be a long path :) . You need to be confident with Javascript and ajax to work with openlayers. Also, a basic understanding of GIS concepts is required.

Comment: I agree with @x82 you shouldn't waste more time on OL2, upgrading is essential but in your case why not begin the latest version + there is an example ready for use in the official website www.openlayers.org

Comment: Thanks everyone, can we have solution to add popup in this code..?

Answer (score 0):

to add a popup in OpenLayers 2 :

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("yourPopupID",
               new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat),//could be fetched from a DB
               new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
               "yourDescription",//could be fetched from DB
               true);

map.addPopup(popup);
```

now this is enough for the example of code you provided in your question, you can retrieve your data from a datbase using an AJAX call to a php script that will do the work